# Cordova - Windows8 does not recognise navigator.notification.alert

Tags: windows-8, cordova-3

I am having a hard time getting cordova to work as I expect.

Here are the steps I have taken.

```
npm install -g cordova

md apps
cd apps

cordova create win8 com.win8.tryout win8tryout

cordova platform add windows8
```

In the www/js folder I edited the index.js adding

```
navigator.notification.alert('try me out');
```

to the device ready event.
Then I build the cordova project from the apps/win8 folder

```
cordova build
```

Then I opened the visual studio solution in the platforms/windows8 folder and ran the application.

The code fails at the `navigator.notification.alert('try me out');` line with 
"JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'alert' of undefined or null reference"

I suspect that the build process isn't working correctly because the cordova.js file in the windows8/www directory is only 52kb and I was expecting a file of about 300kb.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so a bit more research and I realised my sort comings.

From the documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html):
"From version 3.0 onward, Cordova implements all device APIs as plugins..."

I had originally downloaded v2.9.1 which did not implement the plugin architecture.